# Get adjacent objects (tiles) using Colliders? (Unity)

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, grid, tile, collider

I'm trying to make a script for every section of cable that detects adjacent cables through colliders. I'm making it with colliders because there are mechanisms such as switchers and I think it's easier by this way to detect which path the "light" has to follow.

I've tried this code but didn't work and no gameobject is added to the List:

```
 public class cable : MonoBehaviour {
     List<GameObject> connections = new List<GameObject>();
     void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {
         connections.Add(col.gameObject);
     }
 }
```

Here you have a image of how it looks:
[image]

Comment: Are the colliders touching/overlapping or really just adjacent? If they overlap right away, `OnCollisionStay` would probably be the better on, but I'm not sure this is a practical solution overall.

Comment: I think some sort of graph would be better for this.

Comment: Does at least one of your objects have a RigidBody attached to it? There's not currently enough information supplied for us to properly assist you. (It'd just become a guessing game of probable causes...)

Comment: @Serlite That's actually a thing that came to my mind too. At least every other part of the chain would have to have a rigidbody. I don't know how many of those detection sections you have, but if it's some you will probably get performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this long time ago. I used exact coordinates instead of colitions.